# Django ORM Get users who have NOT updated their salary information in the last 1 year (Simlpe History )

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-simple-history

I want to bring users who have not updated their salary information in the last 1 year. BUT WITH ORM not For Loop.

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords



class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    salary_expectation = models.IntegerField()
    history = HistoricalRecords(cascade_delete_history=True)
```

################################################################

```
    User.objects.filter(# MAGIC )  # Get users who have NOT updated their salary information in the last year
```

Comment: Not sure about simple_history for doing that... Have you found any documentation about filtering historical records anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

I can see that this is a package which has its documentation in querying its entries, see below:
https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html

nevertheless you can do that intuitively following Django's normal behavior and a couple of SQL knowledge, I'd expect that history field's table most likely has a one-to-many relationship with the users table, so what I'd do is first open the database, find the column that shows the date of change, write down its name and then write this ORM query below

```
sub_query =  ~Q(history__history_date__lte= "Replace with end of date", history__history_date__gte= "Replace with beginning of date", salary_expectation__isnull=False)

users = User.objects.filter(sub_query)
```

dont forget to import Q

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but How does it know if it has updated the salary_expectation information in this query?

Comment: You're most welcome, okay so I expect this history table to be updated with entries whenever someone adds, removes, changes an entry regarding the User's table I would also expect another column within the history table holding the affected User attributed for example affected_column, let me edit my above answer to fit your needs, but you'll have to take a screenshot of the table's column so I can give you the exact code to write.

Comment: Is it a screenshot of the history table you want?

Comment: Yes if possible :)

Comment: Ok perfect, I am not seeing any date columns though, is there a hidden column anywhere you need to scroll to?

Comment: other than a normal user model there is only a field named "history_date","history_id","history_user_id" :(

Comment: Yess its history_date

Comment: but history__date_salary_expectation__lte  it is not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249014/discussion-between-letorky-and-berkay).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check `HistoricalRecords` class for this information.

1. Add `created_at` and `updated_at` (date_time_fields) fields to your `User` model

```
class User(...):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

2. Queryset Code

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now, ExtractDay
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

users = User.objects.annotate(
                # Calculate duration between now and last update date saved
                duration=models.ExpressionWrapper(
                    Now() - models.F("updated_at"),
                    output_field=models.DurationField()
                ),

                # Extract the amount of days in the duration
                days=ExtractDay('duration'),

                # Check if the number of days between the 2 fields exceeds 1 year (365.25 Days)
                last_update_beyond_a_year=models.Case(
                    models.When(
                        models.Q(days__gte=365.25),
                        then=True
                    ),
                    default=False,
                    output_field=models.BooleanField()
                )
            # Then filter 
            ).filter(last_update_beyond_a_year=True)
```

and Voila !

Comment: thank you so much but but this will not apply to existing users. so i think i need use the HistoricalRecords